# kubectl apply -f works on PC but not in Gitlab Runner

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, kubernetes-deployment

I am trying to deploy to kubernetes using Gitlab CICD. No matter what I do, `kubectl apply -f helloworld-deployment.yml --record` in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` always returns that the deployment is unchanged:

```
$ kubectl apply -f helloworld-deployment.yml --record
 deployment.apps/helloworld-deployment unchanged
```

Even if I change the tag on the image, or if the deployment doesn't exist at all. However, if I run `kubectl apply -f helloworld-deployment.yml --record` from my own computer, it works fine and updates when a tag changes and creates the deployment when no deployment exist. Below is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` that I'm testing with:

```
image: docker:dind
services:
    - docker:dind

stages:
    - deploy

deploy-prod:
    stage: deploy
    image: google/cloud-sdk
    environment: production
    script:
        - kubectl apply -f helloworld-deployment.yml --record
```

Below is `helloworld-deployment.yml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: helloworld-deployment
spec:
    replicas: 2
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: helloworld
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: helloworld
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: helloworld
                  image: registry.gitlab.com/repo/helloworld:test
                  imagePullPolicy: Always
                  ports:
                  - containerPort: 3000
            imagePullSecrets:
                - name: regcred
```

**Update:**

This is what I see if I run `kubectl rollout history deployments/helloworld-deployment` and there is no existing deployment:

```
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "helloworld-deployment" not found
```

If the deployment already exists, I see this:

```
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         kubectl apply --filename=helloworld-deployment.yml --record=true
```

With only one revision.

I did notice this time that when I changed the tag, the output from my Gitlab Runner was:

```
deployment.apps/helloworld-deployment configured
```

However, there were no new pods. When I ran it from my PC, then I did see new pods created.

**Update:**

Running `kubectl get pods` shows two different pods in Gitlab runner than I see on my PC.

I definitely only have one kubernetes cluster, but `kubectl config view` shows *some* differences (the server url is the same). The output for `contexts` shows different namespaces. Does this mean I need to set a namespace either in my `yml` file or pass it in the command? Here is the output from the Gitlab runner:

```
 apiVersion: v1
 clusters:
 - cluster:
     certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
     server: URL
   name: gitlab-deploy
 contexts:
 - context:
     cluster: gitlab-deploy
     namespace: helloworld-16393682-production
     user: gitlab-deploy
   name: gitlab-deploy
 current-context: gitlab-deploy
 kind: Config
 preferences: {}
 users:
 - name: gitlab-deploy
   user:
     token: [MASKED]
```

And here is the output from my PC:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: URL
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: do-nyc3-helloworld
    user: do-nyc3-helloworld-admin
  name: do-nyc3-helloworld
current-context: do-nyc3-helloworld
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: do-nyc3-helloworld-admin
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - kubernetes
      - cluster
      - kubeconfig
      - exec-credential
      - --version=v1beta1
      - --context=default
      - VALUE
      command: doctl
      env: null
```

It looks like Gitlab adds their own [default for namespace](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/#deployment-variables):

```
<project_name>-<project_id>-<environment>
```

Because of this, I put this in the metadata section of helloworld-deployment.yml:

```
namespace: helloworld-16393682-production
```

And then it worked as expected. It was deploying before, but `kubectl get pods` didn't show it since that command was using the `default` namespace.

Comment: What you can see in the ```kubectl rollout history deployments/helloworld-deployment``` and ```kubectl rollout status deployments/helloworld-deployment```

Comment: @AnuradhaFernando I've added an update above.

Comment: It might be silly, but could you once check if you have proper kubeconfig loaded on the pipeline.

Comment: @BinaryBullet when I run `kubectl config view`, the server URL is the same as what I see when I run that on my PC.

Comment: @BinaryBullet but even though the URL is the same, I do notice different pod names when I run `kubectl get pods`. And I do see that the gitlab context from `kubectl config view` has a namespace, when the one on my PC doesn't. I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: @BinaryBullet I think you put me on the right track. I've updated with some more details above.

Comment: Do you tried to change the kubectl context to use the correct namespace? You should try: `kubectl config use-context  helloworld-16393682-production`.

Comment: @srchulo Cool! This is usual behaviour with pipelines, you can go with deployment having namespace and deploy as you mentioned. But the drawback is you need to stick to single namespace for all your applications. I am not sure about Git CI/CD, just check for some option where you can paste the same config file as you have in your pc. So that it would be easy to have different namespaces for different apps. Or you can have different contexts and do something like rabello suggested changing context for each deployment like prod context dev context etc.

Comment: @rabello thanks! That helps and solves my problem :)

Comment: @BinaryBullet thanks! That's a lot of good information, and I appreciate you helping me figure out what was wrong :)

Comment: @srchulo, Great! I've posted a answer with more context about namespaces. Consider to accept if it solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Gitlab use a custom namespace you need to add a namespace flag to you command to display your pods:

`kubectl get pods -n helloworld-16393682-production`

You can set the default namespace for kubectl commands. See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/#setting-the-namespace-preference).

> You can permanently save the namespace for all subsequent kubectl commands in that contex

In your case it could be:

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=helloworld-16393682-production
```

Or if you are using [multiples cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/), you can switch between namespaces using:

```
kubectl config use-context helloworld-16393682-production
```

In this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-context-and-configuration) you can see a lot of useful commands and configurations.

I hope it helps! =)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up adding the namespace in my helloworld-deployment.yml, and then I could still do `kubectl -f apply helloworld-deployment.yml --record`